# $G=\langle a\rangle H$ for subgroup $H$

Tags: gr.group-theory

Dear All,

if $G$ is a group and $\langle a\rangle$ -- any its cyclic subgroup, is it true that there always exists a proper subgroup $H$ in $G$ with $G=\langle a\rangle H$? If "no", would it still be true for finite groups $G$?

Thank you!

P.S.: motivation comes from this -- one my colleague applied mathematician asked me if that would be true -- it somehow appears in his research, and I cannot see any counter-example to this.

Comment: Assuming you do want $H$ to be proper (otherwise this is silly), no: take $G=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ and $a$ the class of $2$.

Comment: You are right! Please kill me somebody!

Comment: You should reserve your death for something of more moment. :-)

Comment: More generally, this is obviously false for any non-cyclic group with a unique maximal proper subgroup.

Comment: Ok, can I ask then -- when Todd-Coxeter gives us a subgroup?

Comment: (Finite groups with a unique maximal proper subgroup are all cyclic, so Jack's examples are infinite)

Comment: It is not clear how to make sense of the question in your comment, victor.

Comment: Well, about Todd-Coxeter -- you know there is famous Todd-Coxeter enumeration procedure to find out the coset reps for f.p. groups wrt to their f.g. subgroups. Can we draw from there when we can find the coset reps forming a subgroup?

Comment: Since this site is intended to be for research level problems, you should really ask questions like this on math.stackexchange

Comment: It is unfortunate that this was closed. I remember in my graduate student days that the same question for a higher rank lattice, say, a lattice in $SL_3({\mathbb R})$  was an unsolved problem (and was attributed to Robert Zimmer).   

Answer (score 5):

One way to see many counterxamples for finite groups is to note that if $G$ has even order, then $G$ contains an element $a$ of order $2$. Any proper subgroup $H$ of $G$ with $G = \langle a \rangle H$ would have to be normal, since subgroups of index $2$ are always normal. Hence every non-trivial perfect finite group $G$ (of even order) provides a counterexample. In particular, every non-Abelian finite simple group (of even order) does. The parentheses are because every non-trivial perfect finite group does in fact have even order, but even without knowing that, there are plenty of explicit examples.